# Validate a number as a positive number

Tags: javascript

I have validated a number as a positive number but it is not giving correct answer i.e it is accepting negative numbers also. Where did I go wrong?

```
<script type="javascript">
    function validatenumber(){
        var class1=document.getElementById("class");
        if((parseInt)class1.value<0){
            alert("Please enter positive integer");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="addbook" action="addbook.php" method="get" onsubmit="validatenumber();">
     Code:<br/><input type="text" name="code"><br/>
     Class:<br/><input type="number" name="class"><br/>
     title:<br/><input type="text" name="title"><br/>
     price:<br/><input type="number" name="price"><br/>
     quantity:<br/><input type="number" name="quantity"><br/>
     category:<br/><input type="text" name="category"><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"><br/>
 </form>
```

Comment: how is validatenumber() being called?

Comment: are you sure that `document.getElementById("class")` is getting the correct item?

Comment: How come no one in the comments has noticed the obvious syntax error yet? It’s not `(parseInt)class1.value`, it’s `parseInt(class1.value)` if anything. Better yet, `parseInt(class1.value, 10)` or simply `Number(class1.value)`.

Comment: See Kevin's answer for the solution.

Comment: still accepting negative numbers

Comment: There is no element with an ID `class`. There’s an element with the name `class` however. Use `document.getElementsByName("class")[0]` instead of `document.getElementById("class")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this:

```
(parseInt)class1.value<0
```

should be:

```
parseInt(class1.value, 10) < 0
```

The 10 will force it to be evaluated as base 10 and not allow JavaScript to "guess" as to which base it thinks it is.  In previous versions of ECMAScript, having a string with a "0" at the start will trick parseInt into thinking that the number should be interpreted as octal.

[ParseInt Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

You are also trying to get the element by id, and you have specified by name.

```
Class:<br/><input type="number" name="class"><br/>
```

you can either give the element an id, or you can use

```
var class1=document.getElementsByName("class")[0];
```

instead of:

```
var class1=document.getElementById("class");
```

and 
you have `type="javascript"` and it should be `language="javascript"`

https://jsfiddle.net/wvapgjs6/1/

Comment: Don't forget the radix! `parseInt(class1.value, 10)`

Comment: still the same answer

Comment: forgot needing to update the javascript tag.  I've also attached a JSFiddle

Comment: I dont the exact reason why it is not executing in my computer. I guess this is the reason: my page url is already adminhome.php?action=addbook so after submitting form it changes to addbook.php. so how to overcome this problem?

Comment: if I understand correctly make the action in the form this: action="addbook.php?action=addbook"

Comment: It works fine if I use `doucment.getElementsByName` only but not `document.getElementById` even if I use id field. What is the reason? here is that code  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wvapgjs6/1/)

Comment: I don't have any problem with using the id field.  Here is a link to the code with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/wvapgjs6/3/